# Inductor sign with single line on the top

Tags: pcb, circuits

I am new to schematics, so can someone help me understand what this part of the circuit means? What does "FB" stand for there, and which components should I use? I guess these are inductors, but not usual ones.

This is part of the audio system, so can it use the usual inductors?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

FB means ferrite bead.

In the first circuit the beads are not used and 0R resistors are used instead.

In the second circuit, these are used.

There is no mention what parameters (impedance, current rating or series resistance) is used.